# Android Gradle Library Dep

Tags: java, android, maven, groovy, build.gradle

so pretty simple I'm working on making an Open Source, Gradle library for my companies API.  We've released the first build of it and works great.  However I'm seeking to make the import process easier for people who want to grab our SDK/Library and include in theirs.

However since require a few things for the library to work at full capacity I declared them as dependancies in the Library's build.gradle.  Works fine when it's being pulled from a Local repo, but when using the MavenCentral, I don't get the build files merging.

How can I stream line putting in the gms libraries and other gradle dependencies my Library needs and make it smoother on the user.

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.qwasi:QwasiSDK:2.1.0@aar' //our library
    compile 'com.thetransactioncompany:jsonrpc2-base:1.38'
    compile 'com.thetransactioncompany:jsonrpc2-client:1.15'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.5.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.5.0'
}
```

to say something like this

```
dependencies{
   compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include ['*.jar'])
   compile 'com.google.android.gms:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
   compile 'com.qwasi:QwasiSDK:2.1.0@aar'
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this? Is this because my javadoc not correct?